# Как заставить работать Zend Optimizer для php 5.3?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Здравствуйте. 
Имеется Windows-машина,  с поднятым на ней веб-сервером. Никак не могу заставить на ней работать Zend Optimizer для установленного php 5.3

Скачал с сайта Zend Technologies лаунчер для запуска Zend php 5.3.
Прописал в php.ini путь и строку запуска... и не могу понять, что не так?

```
zend_extension="D:\PHP\ZendLoader.dll"
zend_loader.enable=1
```

Может быть я просто что-то не понимаю и Zend работает? Вот тут phpinfo: http://109.248.78.238/ 
Где в phpinfo должно быть видно, что Zend работает?

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть вот так:

[image]

Там всё сложно: для PHP версии 5.3. Zend Guard Loader только для запуска зашифрованного кода (в нём нет Optimization Pass, только License Path и Obfuscation level), причём зашифровывать его надо именно под Loader 5.3 (для этого есть специальная версия Zend Guard-a).

В составе Zend Server есть Optimizer+, он предназначен для "Bytecode acceleration", вот только я не помню, он в версии 5.2 или 5.3...

[Скачать тут, есть и 5.2 и 5.3 версии](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/downloads)

Comment: Какая неприятность :( Хоть возвращайся на php 5.2 :(

Comment: Не надо возвращаться, ветка 5.2 уже год не поддерживается